# Creating objects in VBA and VBS

Tags: vba, vbscript

Recently in trying to access the properties and methods of the windows firewall  in [vba](/questions/tagged/vba) I referenced `hnetcfg.dll` and was able to dimension variables for objects like `inetfwMGr`, `inetfwPolicy` etc.

But I couldn't create objects for them as required e.g.
`set obj = new inetfwmgr`
 wouldn't work

Reading around I learned I needed to use
`CreateObject("hnetcfg.FwMgr")`
 to progress any further.

What I want to know is how one can learn which objects can be created from a given dll in VBA. looking at the reference [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366319%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). I can't find a single clue to indicate that you need to create an object `hnetcfg.FwMgr` to be able to proceed. Why `FwMgr`? How can I discover if there are other objects that be created from `hnetgfg.dll`? Is this information supposed to be a in a reference I haven't seen or is implicit from some looking at the properties of `hnetcfg`?

Any insight would be appreciated.Thanks

Answer (score 5):

I don't know anything about this dll, but I think this will help.

You can use CreateObject, and you may want to in the long run for increased portability. This is called "late binding." On the other hand, if you've set the reference to the dll, you can then dimension and create new NetFwLibLib objects ("early binding").  The advantage here is that you'll get intellisense and can examine its properties in the object browser.  Here's some code written in the Excel VBE:

```
Sub test()
Dim test As NetFwTypeLib.INetFwMgr
Set test = New NetFwTypeLib.INetFwMgr
With test
    .CurrentProfileType = ...
End With
End Sub
```

In addition you can use the Object Browser to examine FwTypeLib.  Just click F2 (in Excel's VBE in this case) and you'll see something like this:

[image]

Comment: Is this some version of Visual Studio?

Comment: @natemrice You bet.  I updated my answer to clarify.  Thanks.

Comment: Hi Thanks for describing the difference between early and late binding. However this goes back to the root of my problem. Copying and pasting your code into VBA (with the appropriate reference set) gives an 'invalid use of new keyword message'. I don't get this when I use CreateObject("hnetcfg.fwMgr"). What is special about fwMgr from all of the other types in the dll? I want to understand this because I don't think the type viewer shows that it has any special characteristics

Answer (score 2):

You need to use a type library viewer.  I strongly recommend [TLViewer](http://www.tlviewer.org/tlviewer/).

[iTripoli](http://www.itripoli.com/itlv.asp) also has a decent one.

There are also plenty of scripting references for Windows Firewall.

[Windows Firewall Tools and Settings Scripting Reference](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc737845%28v=ws.10%29.aspx#BKMK_scripting)

[Windows Firewall Scripting (ActiveXperts)](http://www.activexperts.com/activmonitor/windowsmanagement/scripts/networking/windowsfirewall/)

Comment: Thanks but as with my comment above - The type viewer doesn't shed any light on why I can't use set f = new inetfwMgr but I can use CreateObject("hnetcfg.fwMgr"), or even why I can create an object fwMgr, but not fwMgrPolicy - what distinguishes the two other than the idea that a policy obviously belongs to something, but how do I know to create the fwMgr first?

Comment: New and PublicNotCreatable : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa242107(v=vs.60).aspx

Comment: Using New and CreateObject are not the same thing.  They can't be compared because they do different things. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Aa241758 How do you know which objects to create?  By reading the documentation or by trial and error. (And sometimes by examing the object code itself.)